# Reset textboxes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

A few weeks ago I asked for some help in making a reset button, I'm new to python and a Noob in it, mostly I work in c++ & c# also SQL anyways I'm making a reset button for a game, and I cant get it to work. here is the code. The problem seems to be that it can't delete the text in the textboxes after it has been posted, but it can delete the labels and reset them. That the user inputs, the first to lines in def reset(self): that end with _ent are reseted but not the remaining textboxes.

```
    def reset(self):
       self.name_ent.delete(0, END)
       self.gissa_ent.delete(0, END)
       self.display1_txt.delete(0,END)
       self.display2_txt.delete(0,END)
       self.display3_txt.delete(0,END)
       self.display4_txt.delete(0,END)
   # Text for welcome messeage shown in a textbox
    self.display1_txt = Text(self, width = 45, height = 1, wrap = WORD)
    self.display1_txt.grid(row = 8, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
```

The error message I get is following and Yes I'm using Tkinter.

```
 File "/Users/andrej/Desktop/A.Curcic Laboration 3 SU", line 81, in reset
    self.display1_txt.delete(0,END)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2915, in delete
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'delete', index1, index2)
TclError: bad text index "0"
```

Comment: You should explain it better if you want an useful answer. Is it tkinter ? How does it fail ? Could you post a <30 lines of a complete example (instead of repeating display1, display2, etc) which ypu expect to work ?

Comment: Yes! I edited it, sorry for poor explanation earlier!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Tkinter, text indexes are expressed as "row.column" (in your case "1.0"), [see here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm).

Try

```
self.display1_txt.delete("1.0",END)
```

Comment: oooh thank you very much! It's always the little things that error your stuff :) Cheers!

Comment: @andrejcurcic: don't forget to accept the answer (the tick on the left) if it is provided what you need. So that others can see that the question is answered completely.